# how to get the closest number to zero in a loop

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to make a program that print the closest number to zero without using arrays I tried to print the minimum number as it will be the closest number to zero but this doesnot work when one of the numbers is negative

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = in.nextInt();
    int t = 0;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        t = in.nextInt();
        if (t < min) {
            min = t;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(min);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the smallest number or the number closest to zero?

Comment: There is a difference between the minimum number and the closest to zero. For example in {1,-2,4,3,2}, 1 is the closest to 0, but -2 is the smallest. What do you mean?

Comment: I know that but I dont know how to get the closest number to zero so I write minimum number because it will get the closest number to zero if there is not any negative number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the number closest to zero, then you should be checking for the smallest absolute value of the input:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    t = in.nextInt();
    if (Math.abs(t) < Math.abs(min)) {
        min = t;
    }
}
```

Note carefully that we need to use the absolute value on both sides of the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current situation, you can use the absolute value of the entered value (`Maths.abs`) to compare the values when looking for the desired result.

So in the case of `-2` and `1`, the absolute values are `2` and `1` respectively, in which `1 < 2` and would be the value closest to `0`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = in.nextInt();
    int t = 0;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        t = in.nextInt();

        if (Math.abs(t) < Math.abs(min)) {
            min = t;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(min);
}
```